# Show more than nine numbers after decimal point

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc

I am in a situation of dealing with numbers when there is need to display the numbers as is on the Excel sheet. Currently `37.6172080480001` is being displayed as `37.617208048`. Seems like the sheet by default only displays nine digits after the decimal point.

How can that be updated to show more digits after the decimal point?

Currently the number formatting option when applied to the whole sheet adds unwanted 000 to numbers that do not have those many digits beyond it. So we need a solution to increase the system default without adding any unneeded 0's.

Comment: In Excel the number format `General` displays only 11 digits with the decimal point as one of those. So it should be `37.61720805`. Is this question related to Excel or OpenOffice or Google-Docs? Or how to all together?

Comment: In the question header I mentioned open-office.

Comment: In OpenOffice it's called Calc. Can you edit your question to replace Excel with calc, and on the tags too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase shown numbers after the decimal point by this:
`Tools -> Options -> OpenOffice.org Calc -> Calculate`
Set flag "**Limit decimals for general number format**" and set maximum number in input box (for me it's 20).

Comment: Wow that's it amazing